# Google cloud build - custom machine type

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-build

I'm using the Google Cloud Build service to create images of my application. I created a build `trigger` that looks for a git `tag` in a specific format. Each time that Cloud Build detects a new tag, a new build is performed.

Since the build time is pretty long, I am trying to make it faster.

I found that it's possible to ask Google to build the application on a faster machine ([Source](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/speeding-up-builds)).

```
gcloud builds submit --config=cloudbuild.yaml --machine-type=n1-highcpu-8 .
```

This code works if you choose the manual build option. Since I created the build trigger from the GCP user interface, I can't find any place to define the `machine-type` argument.

How can I choose the `machine-type` on automatic build triggers?

### UPDATE:

In the `Trigger` window, I chose `Build Configuration`=`Docker File` and this is my docker file preview:

```
docker build \
    -t gcr.io/PROJ_NAME/APP_NAME/$TAG_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA \
    -f deployments/docker/APPNAME.docker \
    .
```

How should my `buildconfig.yaml` file look like?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to change to Build Configuration=`Cloud Build configuration file`, and commit the `cloudbuild.yaml` to git.

Then use the `machineType` field in the [`options`](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/build-config#options) property of your `cloudbuild.yaml` file.

E.g

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['build', '-t', 'gcr.io/PROJ_NAME/APP_NAME/$TAG_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA', '-f', 'deployments/docker/APPNAME.docker', '.']
options:
 machineType: 'N1_HIGHCPU_8'
```

Comment: What the `gcr.io/myproject/myimage` mean?

Comment: This is where your image is stored when you run Cloud Build. More info [here](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/configuring-builds/store-images-artifacts)

Comment: @No1Lives4Ever you can ignore that, all you need to worry about is the `options:` and `machineType:` type bits - if you post your full cloud build.yaml in the question I can update my answer to just use that...

Comment: @Rich, See my update above. I shared my docker file preview. I hope you can convert it to `cloudbuild.yaml` somehow.